# Ask the user for a number between 1 and 15 (check it using while loop) and print a row of that many stars?

Tags: c

If the user enters 5 it should print

```
* * * * *
```

This is what I have so far. Please help. Tell me what is wrong. The output just keeps printing `*`. It won't stop.

```
    //declare variables 
    int star;
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 15: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    while(num<1||num>15){
    printf("Invalid input\nPlease re-enter: ");
    }
    for(star=num;num<15;num--){
    printf("* ");
    }
```

Comment: What is to stop loop `while(num<1||num>15){
    printf("Invalid input\nPlease re-enter: ");
    }` once it is entered?  Need to change `num` in the loop.

Comment: You are decrementing num for as long as it is less than 15. It will always be less than 15.

Answer (score 2):

Write the second loop the following way

```
while ( num-- ) printf("* ");
```

And the first loop must to have the scanf statement

```
int num = 0;

printf("Enter a number between 1 and 15: ");

while( scanf("%i", &num) == 1 && ( num<1||num>15 )){
    printf("Invalid input\nPlease re-enter: ");
    num = 0;
}
```

As result you will have the following code

```
int num = 0;

printf("Enter a number between 1 and 15: ");

while( scanf("%i", &num) == 1 && ( num < 1 || num > 15 ) ){
    printf("Invalid input\nPlease re-enter: ");
    num = 0;
}

while ( num-- ) printf("* ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    int num,i;
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 15: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num<1||num>15){
    printf("Invalid input\nPlease re-enter: ");
    }
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
      printf("*");
    }
```